# Lower Central Series for $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

> Describe the Lower Central Series for $S_5$.

I know that the commutator subgroup $[G,G] = A_5$. So the first two terms of the series are $$ S_5 \supset A_5. $$

The next element is $[S_5,A_5].$

> How do I find this?
>
> I think that it can't be $\{e\}$ since that would say that $A_5$ is abelian. (maybe?)
>
> Is $[S_5,A_5]$ necessarily normal in $A_5$?
> If it is, then $[S_5,A_5] = A_5,$ but I couldn't find that result. . .

Comment: $[S_5,A_5]=e$ would mean that each element of $S_5$ commutes with each element of $A_5$; it would imply that $A_5$ is **central** in $S_5$ (a stronger statement than saying it is abelian). Note that the terms of the lower central series are normal in the group, so they are certainly normal in any subgroup that contains them. Alternatively, notice that $[A_5,A_5]\subseteq [S_5,A_5]\subseteq [S_5,S_5]$.

Comment: So in general $[G,G']$ has to be normal in **both** $G$ and $G'$?

Comment: It has to be normal in $S_5$, and *therefore*, since it is contained in $A_5$, also normal in $A_5$. If you have a group $G$, a subgroup $N\triangleleft G$, and a subgroup $H\leq G$, if $N\subseteq H$ then $N\triangleleft H$. Normality in the larger group implies normality in the subgroup.